# carbon-addons-iot-react bundle size too big

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, webpack, carbon-design-system

I have an CRA typescript installiation and I'm using carbon-addons-iot-react design library.
https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-addons-iot-react

When i check with source-map-explorer i saw my bundle size extremely big because of the carbon-addons-iot-react imports watson icon in a odd way.

You can see it in picture;
[source-map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHrG.png)

I tried to tree-shaking way to import icons inside my components

```
import { Add16 } from "@carbon/icons-react"; //this to
import Add from "@carbon/icons-react/es/add/16"; //this
```

but i think the reason is the way carbon-addons-iot-react imports icons.

I also tried route based code splitting but it's not reducing bucket sizes.

[sizes-after-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbMlo.png)

I research a little bit for _generated folder and why it's too big. But i can't find anything on the web or issues on their repository. They use PURE React.CreateElement inside buckets, but for some reason my webpack cant threeshake on them if it's the problem.

Anybody have some ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue to this and tracked it down to an import of components from UIShell, which was causing the whole icons library to be included in the bundle.

Switch any full path imports from UIShell to import from the top level instead.

Before:

```
import { HeaderNavigation } from "carbon-components-react/lib/components/UIShell";
```

After:

```
import { HeaderNavigation } from "carbon-components-react";
```